# How to let `cabal install` ignore the local `.cabal` file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

#### Versions

```
%cabal --version     
cabal-install version 3.6.2.0
compiled using version 3.6.2.0 of the Cabal library
%ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7
```

#### Problem

I want to install [`weeder`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/weeder). If there is no `*.cabal` file in the current directory, running `cabal install weeder` succeeds. However, if the one exists and contains a dependency that conflicts with what `weeder` requires, `cabal install weeder` fails.

For example, if a `.cabal` file contains `text < 1.2.3.0` as `build-depends`, `cabal install weeder` fails with the message below:

```
%cabal install weeder
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: foobarbaz-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] next goal: text (dependency of foobarbaz)
[__1] rejecting: text-1.2.4.1/installed-1.2.4.1 (conflict: foobarbaz =>
text<1.2.3.0)
[__1] skipping: text-1.2.5.0, text-1.2.4.1, text-1.2.4.0, text-1.2.3.2,
text-1.2.3.1, text-1.2.3.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the
previous version to fail: excluded by constraint '<1.2.3.0' from 'foobarbaz')
[__1] trying: text-1.2.2.2
[__2] next goal: deepseq (dependency of text)
[__2] rejecting: deepseq-1.4.4.0/installed-1.4.4.0 (conflict: text =>
base>=4.2 && <4.11, deepseq => base==4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0)
[__2] trying: deepseq-1.4.5.0
[__3] next goal: array (dependency of text)
[__3] rejecting: array-0.5.4.0/installed-0.5.4.0 (conflict: text => base>=4.2
&& <4.11, array => base==4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0)
[__3] trying: array-0.5.4.0
[__4] next goal: base (dependency of foobarbaz)
[__4] rejecting: base-4.14.3.0/installed-4.14.3.0 (conflict: text => base>=4.2
&& <4.11)
[__4] skipping: base-4.16.0.0, base-4.15.0.0, base-4.14.3.0, base-4.14.2.0,
base-4.14.1.0, base-4.14.0.0, base-4.13.0.0, base-4.12.0.0, base-4.11.1.0,
base-4.11.0.0 (has the same characteristics that caused the previous version
to fail: excluded by constraint '>=4.2 && <4.11' from 'text')
[__4] rejecting: base-4.10.1.0, base-4.10.0.0, base-4.9.1.0, base-4.9.0.0,
base-4.8.2.0, base-4.8.1.0, base-4.8.0.0, base-4.7.0.2, base-4.7.0.1,
base-4.7.0.0, base-4.6.0.1, base-4.6.0.0, base-4.5.1.0, base-4.5.0.0,
base-4.4.1.0, base-4.4.0.0, base-4.3.1.0, base-4.3.0.0, base-4.2.0.2,
base-4.2.0.1, base-4.2.0.0, base-4.1.0.0, base-4.0.0.0, base-3.0.3.2,
base-3.0.3.1 (constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed
instance)
[__4] fail (backjumping, conflict set: base, foobarbaz, text)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: base, text, deepseq, array, foobarbaz
Try running with --minimize-conflict-set to improve the error message.
```

I can avoid this by `mv foobarbaz.cabal foobarbaz.cabal.bk` before `cabal install weeder` and `mv foobarbaz.cabal.bk foobarbaz.cabal` after the install, or running `cabal install weeder` in the other directory. But is there an option to ignore the local `.cabal` file?

Comment: Anything wrong with simply `(cd ~ ; cabal install weeder)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I posted the question, I found that the `-z` and `--ignore-project` options are also what I wanted.

```sh
cabal install -z weeder
```

Comment: `--ignore-project` should probably be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Cabal has a `--project-file` option. It turns out that when specified empty, this causes cabal-install to not use *any* project file, even when one is in the current directory.

```sh
cabal v2-install --project-file="" weeder
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. BTW by chance, do you know why cabal tries to resolve dependencies with the local project? I feel it's weird since there is no need to build the binary with the local project.

Comment: @toku-sa-n consider e.g. you're the developer a library that the executable depends upon. Maybe a bug was found in that application that turns out to be a downstream issue from your library, and now you try to bisect the breaking change. That could be done by cloning the executable's package and using a dedicated project, but a quicker way is to just ask Cabal to build the executable based on the HEAD of your own project, without ever checking out the executable manually.